# OWIN startup class is not firing in a windows container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, kubernetes, owin

Any idea why my OWIN startup class is not firing in a windows container for an ASP.NET WebForms site?  It works fine when I run it in debug locally. I’ve checked all the classic OWIN mistakes:

- `<add key="owin:appStartup" value="Namespace.Startup" />` IS in my web.config
- `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />` IS in my web.config
- `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` IS NOT in my web.config
- `[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication.Startup))]` IS in the right spot for my startup class
- there IS a reference to `Microsoft.OWIN.System.Host`
- `Microsoft.OWIN.System.Host.dll` is in the bin for the site on the container
- `<add assembly="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.1.0.0" />` IS in my systemweb.compilation.assemblies

That's all I know to check, but it doesn't seem to be firing on app startup.  I know because it's supposed to be hitting an API endpoint for auth but that container isn't logging any requests for the auth endpoint.  The OWIN container is running this image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the startup was firing just fine.  My problem had to do with how environment variables are handled in windows that were causing them not be available to the app pool in my container.